# google sheets email notification when cell changes

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like an email sent when a cell value is above a certain amount

I would like an email sent when cell c6 value  is >=4.Heres the script I'm currently using that does not send me an email

```
function sheetTracker(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();

    if(Session.getActiveUser()!='trdforlife@gmail.com' &&
       Number(ss.getActiveCell().getValue())>=4 && cell=='c6'){
        MailApp.sendEmail('yourmail@gmail.com', 'Modification in the spreadsheet', 
       'Cell ' + cell + ' has been modified by '+ Session.getActiveUser() +
       ' - new value = ' + ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString());
    } 
}`your text`
```

Comment: Some error occur? The e-mail for where you want to send is really is yourmail@gmail.com? And what is the text `your text` in the end of the code?

Comment: Thanks I didn't catch the year email part that's probably the problem. As for your text it was a copied code. I didn't see it so I didn't change it to what I wanted to say.

Comment: It's unclear if you pass your conditions from the IF statement. Maybe this is not ```c6``` but ```C6``` for example

Comment: Well I have tried both near works even with my corrected email

Comment: Do you have any error ?

Comment: no I do not it runs fine or at least appears to

Comment: Add ```Logger.log("ok")``` just before your call to MailApp and run, do you see it in the log?

Comment: I'm really new at this if i add it to the same line i get an error on that line. if I put it on it's own line it runs but there is no log